# How do I get the total percentage of a portion of a column in python?

Tags: python, dataframe

I did this:

```
df_percent = df['total_time'] > 60 
df_total = df_percent/df['total_time'] * 100
df_total

0       0.0
1       0.0
2       0.0
3       0.0
4       0.0
       ... 
1893    0.0
1894    0.0
1895    0.0
1896    0.0
1897    0.0
```

I only need the total percentage, not the individual ones I got. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 2):

```
percent = 100 * len(df.loc[df.total_time > 60]) / len(df)
```